# How to update user data in cloud formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am new to cloud formation ! 
How do we update the user data in cloud formation, does the update stack also update anything that is changed inside the UserData? If not how do we update the User Data changes ? Thanks !

```
"UserData": {
    "Fn::Base64": {
        "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
                "#!/bin/bash\n",
                "apt-get update\n",
                "apt-get -y upgrade\n",
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update anything in your cloudformation template you run an update-stack command with the new or update cloudformation template as an input parameter. AWS will then only alter the components you have changed. So if any line in the userData section has been altered when you run update-stack AWS will run through the entire userData section once again.

THis also means your EC2 instances will be destroyed and replaced by new instances if your change requires updating userData.

**Update:** You can update your EC2 instances user data without destroying if you're EC2 instance is using an EBS drive and you turn it off first. But this is an anti-pattern in my opinion. The EC2 instances is just a VM. You should keep it immutable. If something needs to change rebuild the instance.

Comment: Just stepped over this answer. According to AWS docs this answer is wrong: The UserData section can be updated for powered off instances. So if you update the userdata in the cloud formation template then cloud formation service will power off the instance, update the user data and start it again. But keep in mind that the script will NOT be executed then. See also infotext in aws console while updating userdata: If you stop an instance, modify its user data, and start the instance, the updated user data is not executed automatically when you start the instance.

Comment: I dont know if wrong is the right word. Theres a lot of caveats with doing that and thats also an anti-pattern. Instances are just VMS, let your ELB rebuild them once at a time. They should be treated as immutable. Why use infrastructure as code if you're going to be tweaking individual instances.

Comment: I also updated my answer. I believe the OP just wanted to know how to update his userData.

Answer (score 1):

Userdata can be updated, but it would require stopping and starting of your EBS backed instance :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata

Answer (score 0):

```
"Fn::Join": [
        "/n",
        [
            "#!/bin/bash",
            "apt-get update",
            "apt-get -y upgrade",
        ]
```

actually this is the correct way. Don't know  whether it is just a typo from your side